# Google App Engine Golang Imports not working

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the datastore client library for golang, but it won't work. I downloaded it via the go -t command and also manually by downloading the github files. After the download I have copied the libraries into my google-cloud-sdk folder. But now when I try to start the dev_appserver.py there are so many missing packages. Do I have to import them all manually or is there an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to setup go env. It seems you do not have go env setup. 
For example:

```
11:35 $ go env
...
GOPATH="/Users/.../Goarea"
...
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

Inside you GOPATH you would have bin/pkg/src. So when you do

```
 go get -u cloud.google.com/go/datastore
```

It will be pulled to .../src/cloud.google.com/go/datastore

then you can import pkg and use it in your code.

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "log"
   "net/http"

   "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
   "google.golang.org/api/option"

   // Imports the Google Cloud Datastore client package.
   "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
   "golang.org/x/net/context"
)
...
func main() {
   ctx := context.Background()
   projectID := "your id"
   client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx,
   projectID, option.WithServiceAccountFile("YOUR CREDENTIAL.json"))
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
   }
...
...
```

Comment: Is the google.golang.org/appengine/datastore deprecated? I tried implementing your code into my appengine program, but it won't work. How do I use this inside handler functions?

Comment: I am not sure about appengine. I can see there are examples to construct handle functions take a look at this link https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore

Comment: I think it the same if you just remove godoc.org.